# What is the difference between Joining two different DB Context using ToList() and .AsQueryable()?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

**Case 1:**
I am Joined two different DB Context by `ToList()` method in Both Context.

**Case 2:**
And also tried Joining first Db Context with `ToList()` and second with `AsQueryable()`.

Both worked for me. All I want to know is the difference between those Joinings regarding Performance and Functionality. Which one is better ?

```
var users = (from usr in dbContext.User.AsNoTracking()
                  select new
                  {
                     usr.UserId,
                     usr.UserName
                  }).ToList();

 var logInfo= (from log in dbContext1.LogInfo.AsNoTracking()
               select new
               {
                   log.UserId,
                   log.LogInformation
               }).AsQueryable();

 var finalQuery= (from usr in users
                  join log in logInfo on usr.UserId equals log.UserId
                  select new
                  {
                     usr.UserName,
                     log.LogInformation
                  }.ToList();
```

Comment: I think this join will happen "in-memory", but I am not sure. So User and LogInfo, will be read into memory and joined there.

Comment: You should try the same tests in LinqPad, that should show you the difference in SQL that gets generated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll elaborate answer that was given by Jehof in his comment. It is true that this join will be executed in the memory. And there are 2 reasons why it happens.

Firstly, this join cannot be performed in a database because you are joining an object in a memory (`users`) with a deferred query (`logInfo`). Based on that it is not possible to generate a query that could be send to a database. It means that before performing the actual join a deferred query is executed and all logs are retrieved from a database. To sum up, in this scenario 2 queries are executed in a database and join happens in memory. **It doesn't matter if you use *ToList + AsQueryable* or *ToList  + ToList* in this case.**

Secondly, in your scenario this join can be performed ONLY in a memory. Even if you use `AsQueryable` with the first context and with the second context it will not work. You will get `System.NotSupportedException` exception with the message:

*The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.*

I wonder why you're using 2 DB contexts. Is it really needed? As I explained because of that you lost a possibility to take full advantage of deferred queries (lazy evaluation features).

If you really have to use 2 DB contexts, I'll consider adding some filters (WHERE conditions) to queries responsible for reading users and logs from DB. Why? For small number of records there is no problem. However, for large amount of data it is not efficient to perform joins in memory. For this purpose databases were created.

Comment: thank u for ur response :). And I have doubt, In Case 2 the type doesn't change after Joining. Still it remains as AsQueryable()

Comment: @Arthik So? It's perfectly fine to have an `IQueryable` on an in-memory list. Note that you can use `.ToList().AsQueryable()` just as easily - the result is an queryable on the list. But you still have to get the whole list first :)

Comment: @Arthik You are right that the type of _logInfo_ will not change after a join. In C# you cannot change a type of a variable after it was declared. _logInfo_ is "converted" into a list behind a scene and  the result of this operation is not stored in any variable in your code.

Comment: @Michal, behind the scene means, Is that occur in any temporary memory? How long the memory holds the list?

Comment: @Arthik It occurs in  the memory (RAM) used by your application. This list will be removed from the memory by Garbage Collection when it is not used anymore i.e. there are no references pointing this list.

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't been explained yet why the statements actually work and why EF doesn't throw an exception that you can only use sequences of primitive types in a LINQ statement.

If you swap both lists ...

```
var finalQuery= (from log in logInfo
                 join usr in users on log.UserId equals usr.UserId
                 ...
```

EF will throw

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'User'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

So why does your code work?

That will become clear if we convert your statement to method syntax (which the runtime does under the hood):

```
users.Join(logInfo, usr => usr.UserId, log => log.UserId
            (usr,log) => new
                        {
                            usr.UserName,
                            log.LogInformation
                        }
```

Since `users` is an `IEnumerable`, the extension method [`Enumerable.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534675%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is resolved as the appropriate method. This method accepts an `IEnumerable` as the second list to be joined. Therefore, `logInfo` is implicitly cast to `IEnumerable`, so it runs as a separate SQL statement before it partakes in the join.

In the version `from log in logInfo join usr ...`, [`Queryable.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534644%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is used. Now `usr` is converted into an `IQueryable`. This turns the whole statement into one expression that EF unsuccessfully tries to translate into one SQL statement.

Now a few words on

> Which one is better?

The best option is the one that does just enough to make it work. That means that

- You can remove `AsQueryable()`, because `logInfo` already is an `IQueryable` and it is cast to `IEnumerable` anyway.
- You can replace `ToList()` by `AsEnumerable()`, because `ToList()` builds a redundant intermediate result, while `AsEnumerable()` only changes the runtime type of `users`, without triggering its execution yet.

Answer (score -1):

**ToList()**

- Execute the query immediately
- You will get **all** the elements ready in memory

**AsQueryable()**

- lazy (execute the query later)
- Parameter: `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>`
- Convert Expression into T-SQL (with specific provider), query remotely and load result to your application memory.
- That’s why DbSet (in Entity Framework) also inherits IQueryable to get efficient query.
- It does not load every record. E.g. if Take(5), it will generate select top 5 * SQL in the background.

Comment: This does not answer the question